# Java Calendar arithmetic issue

Tags: java, time, calendar, timeout, math

Having trouble finding a solution for my situation here. Sorry if this has been answered before but I couldn't find one that worked for me.

Problem: Trying to test if a user session has been active for longer than the timeout limit.

I am trying to use the session start time and the current system time and subtract them and if the result is greater than the timeout var - kill the session.

So:

```
 for (LogSession logSession : sessionLogList) {

                Calendar sessionStartTime = logSession.getStartTime();
                Calendar currentSysTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                currentSysTime.setTime(currentSysTime.getTime());
                Calendar activeTime = Calendar.getInstance();

                activeTime.setTime(sessionStartTime.getTime());
                activeTime.add(activeTime.getTime(), - currentSysTime.getTime());

                if ( activeTime.getTime() > timeoutLimit) {
                       // Do something
                }
}
```

I am obviously getting an error message on the activeTime.add line but am unsure of the needed approach here. Any help would be great thanks.

Timeout is currently set to 15 minutes but is a global variable that can be changed.

Comment: What is the error message?  Also, I don't see why the setTime call is necessary here: Calendar currentSysTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                currentSysTime.setTime(currentSysTime.getTime());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample seems to have a few errors in it but here is how I would go about it.

```
Calendar sessionEndTime = logSession.getStartTime();
sessionEndTime.add(Calendar.MINUTE, TIMEOUT_MINS);
Calendar currentSysTime = Calendar.getInstance();
if (currentSysTime.after(sessionEndTime)) {
//do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach brain but i am getting an error on the assignment of sessionEndTime - cannot convert void to Calendar.  Calendar sessionStartTime = logSession.getStartTime();  Calendar currentSysTime = Calendar.getInstance();   Calendar sessionEndTime = sessionStartTime.add(Calendar.MINUTE, timeout_mins);   Any ideas?

Comment: Ooops! Sorry about that, for some reason I assumed that calendar was immutable. Silly silly me. I'll edit my post to reflect what you should do!

Comment: Thanks for the great solution! Best approach suggested!

Answer (score 3):

Read the API, in the calendar.add method its stated you need to specific to what field you want to add too.
Example

```
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 24);
```

But you kinda dont need to use calendar manipulation.

Just make a substraction of curentTimeInMillis versus starting time in millis and if bigger (in millis) then your timeout then you have your answer

```
long refTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long now = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
if ( now - refTime > TIMEOUT ) { 
     ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 for (LogSession logSession : sessionLogList) {

                Calendar sessionStartTime = logSession.getStartTime();
                Long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

                if (now - sessionStartTime.getTimeInMillis() > timeoutLimit) {
                       // Do something
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you compare the session start time and the current time, the result will be that every session has a max age, and will reset rgardless of activity.

You need an attribute for the last activitiy time in your `logSession` object and use that to compare to the current time. If these times are simple `long` fields and assigned the `System.currentTimeMilis()` you dont need `Calendar` arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are in some web container and have a web.xml available. Could you not use standard?

```
<session-config>
 <session-timeout>30</session-timeout> 
</session-config>
```